# How do I fix SAML authentication on Heroku app which works fine on localhost?

Tags: python, django, authentication, heroku, saml

I have a django app that uses SAML authentication to sign in .edu users. I recently upgraded my packages and after a lot of trial and error, I found a set of packages that all work with each other on Python 3.10.

Here are the packages my requirements.txt currently holds that are related to SAML:

```
python3-saml==1.15.0
xmlsec==1.3.13
isodate==0.6.1
six==1.11.0
lxml==4.9.2
```

SAML authentication for .edu users works fine on localhost but I get the following error when I run the application on Heroku Dev.

> SAML Response not found, Only supported HTTP_POST Binding

I used the SAML tracer to check if I was receiving POST data upon sign in and this is what I found:

[image: SAML tracer Parameters]

The Summary tab shows the certificate / key values.

On https://herokuapp/account/?acs this is the error:

```
OneLogin_Saml2_Error at /account/
SAML Response not found, Only supported HTTP_POST Binding
```

I have also observed that I can randomly log in using my .edu user sometimes.

How can I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get SAML to work on my Heroku app finally with just some changes to package versions.

Here are the updated packages that worked on python 3.10 and Django 4.1.7:

```
python3-saml==1.14.0
xmlsec==1.3.13
isodate==0.6.1
six==1.11.0
lxml==4.6.5
```

I had no idea that changing these package versions would be the solution to my problems because this works perfectly on localhost, but I am posting my answer here so others may save some time going over all views / settings instead of just testing lower package versions.